# compare value in two lists and delete row in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I have two data frames and I need to compare values of table 1 with values of table 2.

```
Table 1: (each value correspoding one task)

Value: 5 10 15 20 25 30
Task: a b c d e f

Table 2: (each value corresponding one date)
Value: 4 6 8 12 16 18 22 27
Date: 3 5 8 9 11 18 20 19
```

When the value of table 1 is greater than the value of table 2, I want to get the corresponding tasks and dates. For example:

The output for `table2$value[2] > table1$value[1]` should be task a and date 3.

Also, when the task in table 1 is extracted, I want to delete the corresponding row. For example, the next loop should be:

```
Table 1: 
Value: 10 15 20 25 30
Task:  b c d e f
Table 2: 
Value: 4 6 8 12 16 18 22 27
Date: 1 3 5 8 9 11 18 20 19
-->output: 
table2$value[4]=12 > table1$value[1]= 10 -> output: task b and date 9

    for (i in 1:length(Table2$value)) {
      for (a in 1:length(Table1$value)) {
        if (Table2$value[i]>Table1$value[a]){ 
          x<-table2$date[i]      
          y<-table1$task[a]
          newtable<-data.frame(x,y)
          table1$value<-table1$value[-c(a)]

        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide samples of your data with `dput` or copy and paste them into the question to get the exact way they look like? You can use `dput(head(tablex,n))` and add both to your question.

Comment: In Table 2, you have eight values for `Value` but nine for `Date`.  Should the first `Date` be removed?

Comment: If many values from Table 2 are greater than a value from Table 1, do you want the row with the closest larger value from Table 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)    
tbl1 <- data.table(value=seq(5, 30, 5), task=letters[1:6])
tbl2 <- data.table(value=c(4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 18, 22, 27),
                   date=c(3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 18, 20, 19))

tbl1
##    value task
## 1:     5    a
## 2:    10    b
## 3:    15    c
## 4:    20    d
## 5:    25    e
## 6:    30    f

tbl2
##    value date
## 1:     4    3
## 2:     6    5
## 3:     8    8
## 4:    12    9
## 5:    16   11
## 6:    18   18
## 7:    22   20
## 8:    27   19
```

Rather than using a loop (not that there's anything wrong with that), this answer uses a "rolling join" to find the `value` from `tbl2` that is greater than the one from `tbl1`, and returns the corresponding `date` and `task`:

```
res <- tbl2[tbl1, on="value", roll=-Inf]
## res
##    value date task
## 1:     5    5    a
## 2:    10    9    b
## 3:    15   11    c
## 4:    20   20    d
## 5:    25   19    e
## 6:    30   NA    f
```

For an explanation of rolling joins with examples, refer to [this blog post from Ben Gorman](https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/r-data-table-rolling-joins).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. It's almost output I want. However, I only count `the value of table 2` which closest larger than `value of table 1`.
My expect output is:

```
value date task
5      5    a   
10     9    b 
15     11   c
20     20   d
25     19   e
30     NA   f
```

if the `task` is already extracted in `tbl1`, I want to remove it and start counting from second `value` of `tbl1`.

Comment: This isn't an answer. If you have more information to add to the question, you can [edit] it